# FileInfo finds file, but File.Copy cannot find the file

Tags: c#, .net, file, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I am trying to find a file with the last write date and copy it to a different location. It finds the file correctly, but when I try to copy it, it can't find the file it just found. This is in a SSIS script task.

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"path");
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

//files that have been written to in the last 3 days
DateTime lastWrite = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3); 

foreach (FileInfo latestFile in files)
{  
    // if its the correct name
    if (latestFile.Name.StartsWith("OMC")) 
    {
        // if its in the last 3 days
        if (latestFile.LastWriteTime > lastWrite) 
        {    
            lastWrite = latestFile.LastWriteTime;

            // this correctly find the file and puts it into the file variable.
            file = latestFile.ToString(); 

            // this errors out saying it cannot find the file.
            // (Does not even go to the outputFile)
            File.Copy(file, outputFile, true); // <- error

            //backs the file up 
            File.Copy(file, backupfile, true);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: When you set a breakpoint, does `file` have the full path of the file?

Comment: That's not what he asked.

Comment: just use fullname insated of toString and do not down vote everything vote!

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Please do not post images using outside sites, especially ones that can have inappropriate for work banners, instead add the image to a answer, then copy the link the answer has and put it in your comment. You can discard the answer when you are done.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Didn't realize it had inappropriate content. Removed the comment since the original poster removed all his/her comments too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileInfo.ToString()` returns the name of the file, but in order to copy it, you need the full path. Change

```
file = latestFile.ToString();
```

To

```
file = latestFile.FullName;
```

And give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

What does `latestFile.ToString()` evaluate to? That is a strange way to obtain the path.

Use `FileInfo.FullName` like the docs indicate.

You can use the debugger to find such bugs yourself.

Comment: Nothing more than a commenty.

Comment: Not sure why you think that. I call out the problem and show the solution. What do you say about that?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to construct the full path instead of using [`Fileinfo.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.tostring.aspx):

```
file = latestFile.FullName;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.tostring.aspx):

> there are cases where the string returned by the ToString method does not represent the fully qualified path. For example, when you create a FileInfo object using the GetFiles method, the ToString method does not represent the fully qualified path.